# Newton's bucket and Mach

Tags: reference-frames, inertial-frames, machs-principle

Based on previous q's and a's on this general topic, it seems there is little agreement on whether Mach's analysis is "correct". I am curious about actual experimental tests of a "closed Newton's bucket" in space. For example, if a thick, impervious and transparent sphere is filled with (say) 2/3's water and 1/3 air at sea level and then transported to "outer space", will 100% of the inside surface of the sphere be covered in water and the center air?, vice versa?, a mix? Also, do we believe the sphere will acquire spin from its surroundings once released into space or not?

Comment: *"Based on previous q's and a's on this general topic, it seems..."* To which previous "q's and a's" are you referring? Does it matter for your question?

Comment: How does this surface covering with water or air have anything to do with "Mach's analysis"? Why would the sphere acquire spin from its surroundings in space? Do you assume space with some air left, or vacuum?

Comment: Re: Newton's bucket and Mach... A rotating bucket with water (on earth) will "cavitate" in the center, with water from the center pushed out and up the sides of the bucket. Mach refined our understanding of this. Here's a link to a great description of this at Saint Andrews:  https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/HistTopics/Newton_bucket/

Comment: Here a NASA video of wringing out a wet rag on the space station: https://twitter.com/ScienceGuys_/status/1753024394501521526     Air goes out to the inside surface and water stays in the center...